# iOS Agent is not connecting with the local setup of WSO2 IoT server 3.1.0

Tags: ios, wso2, wso2-iot

I have setup the WSO2 Iot Server 3.1.0 on my local environment in Mac operating system. Server is correctly setup and working fine. Now I am trying to connect the out of box iOS agent provided by the WSO2 with my locally setup wso2 Iot server.

I am getting following error at the last step , when I am enrolling my device using ios agent app.

**Note:**

I am running this application in Simulator not the actual device.

[image]

**Other key points to consider:**

The other key point that is different in my setup, is the following that I didn't generated my organization registration certificate from Apple, since I was setting up on my local machine for personal use only. But maybe that is mandatory and that is why it is giving me error.

Any insight would be helpful . Thanks.

Comment: It is mandatory to follow all the steps in this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/iOS+Configurations) in order to completely setup ios features.

Comment: Hi, IF I install and run iotserver , will I need to integrate the WSO2 App manager with the devicemgt server or it will be by default integrated?

Comment: It is integrated by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but somehow for me it is not working, If you have time, kindly look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791727/unable-to-install-apps-in-mobile-using-wso2-iot-server-3-1-0

Answer (score 1):

In order to proceed, we have to follow the following steps.

In ios device go to General -> About -> Certificate Trust Setting And enable to trust the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that device enrollment and device management capabilities will not be 100% working on simulations.

Please reverify and change your IP from 127.0.0.1 to the real ID given by your routers  DNS server.

You can use an iOS device which is connected to the same network in order to complete the enrollment and evaluate MDM capabilities of IoT Server.

Thanks.