# Unable to install apps in mobile using WSO2 Iot Server 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-appm, wso2-iot

I have installed WSO2 IoT server 3.1.0. The server is running successfully. I am able to log in. I have created few apps in publisher and published them. When I access the app store from my android device. I am not able to install these apps.

**Picture 1:**
[image]
**Picture 2:**
[image]

**Problem :**

When I click on the "NEXT" button , nothing happens. And app is not downloaded.

**CheckList:**

- User have access to installing the apps.
- Device is successfully enrolled with the IoT server.
- Same credentials are being used to accessing the app store as for enrolling the device.

**Questions:**

1. Do WSo2 APP manager and devicemgt solution are pre integrated in IoT server or do I have to do it manually?
2. If these services are pre-configured then how can I make sure that it is correctly configured?
3. Will a list of enrolled devices is shown, when a user clicks on install?

IF someone can give some insights that would be much helpful.

Comment: 1. They are pre-integrated
2. There is no special configuration when you are trying on a local setup
3. If you have enrolled any Android devices a list of devices should be shown.

Follow up-
When try to install through a desktop machine does it work
Do the following, login as admin to the store and click on enterprise install button and select the user you wish to install the app and click install. If the install does not happen, go to the device mgt app(eg-https://localhost:9443/devicemgt) and go to devices->to the correct device and check the operation log for app install command.

Comment: you don't have t log into the store via mobile device simply triggering an install from your laptop or desktop will do the job. you need to select the device you want this application needs to be installed seems to be an issue with the responsiveness of the UI. Have you tried on your PC?